# Camel http4 and url-encoded passwords being interpreted as separate arguments

Tags: url, apache-camel, ntlm

We've got an Apache Camel (2.13.2) app that uses http4 to communicate with a webserver, using NTLM for auth.

The endpoint is defined as (pseudo):

```
...
.to("http4://thegreat.server.com/uri?authUsername=" + user + "&authPassword=" + pass 
   + "&authenticationPreemptive=true&authMethod=NTLM&authDomain=DOMAIN&authHost=host")
.to("otherEndpoint");
```

This works well as long as the `pass` variable contains "non-special" chars.

However, if the `pass` contains for example `"abcd&def"` - Camel will intepret the ampersand as a query parameter separator, as it should.

But url encoding the ampersand (i.e `"abcd%26def"`) makes no difference at all?

We still end up with Camel invoking the endpoint `"http://thegreat.server.com/uri?authMethod=NTLM&def="`, with a truncated password.

Is there something obvious we're missing out on, or does this kind of look like a bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the Camel documentation how to configure endpoint uris

- http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html

There is a section that covers about passwords, eg you should use the RAW() syntax.

So it would be something a like

```
.to("http4://thegreat.server.com/uri?authUsername=" + user + "&authPassword=RAW(" + pass 
   + ")&authenticationPreemptive=true&authMethod=NTLM&authDomain=DOMAIN&authHost=host")
.to("otherEndpoint");
```

Comment: RAW() syntax has only been introduced since Camel 2.11. For those who are still using previous version see my posts [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25555434/628006)