# Camel password being partially logged after sanitization

Tags: encoding, apache-camel, uri, http4s

This question is a follow on from :
[Camel http4 and url-encoded passwords being interpreted as separate arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883501/camel-http4-and-url-encoded-passwords-being-interpreted-as-separate-arguments)
and is somewhat related to [this update](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8607) put in as part of Camel 2.14.x and 2.15.x for sanitizing password information...

We're using Camel 2.14.4 with http4 component to communicate with a webservice, and using the RAW syntax. However, if the password within RAW contains an ampersand, the santizeUri method only masks some of the password text.

E.g. Say my password is me#@123, and is injected into the URI so that it becomes a part of the overall URI as follows: 
...password=RAW(me#@123)..., when the sanitizeURI method is called, it only sanitizes up to the ampersand, and sees the 123 as a different key, so you end up with ******&123 being logged at WARN level in the logs from [this code](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/changelog/camel-git?cs=3e041ab5c0ccf051ba019cfff347f91a38b04516).

Is there any way of avoiding this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah we should remove that WARN logging as its not in use anymore. I have logged a ticket about this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10395

In the older Camel 2.14.4 version you can only configure your logging library to use ERROR level or OFF for the logger name that logs that WARN message.

Comment: Also try upgrading Camel as its likely also fixed in a newer release. For example 2.18.0 does not log the password partially. I only see xxxxxx

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Claus! Have updated the logger level for that class and it looks good. Will look to migrate to a higher version of Camel in one of the upcoming iterations